# Which Firefox version is more compatible with Selenium IDE and Firebug?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, selenium-ide, firebug

Firefox Browser compatibility with Selenium IDE and Firebug Plugins or addons.

Comment: You've got the cart before the horse. You test on the browsers you expect your users will be using. You can't force your users to use a browser because it tests better!

Comment: That question makes sense now, as current versions of Firefox do not support Selenium IDE. You can download previous versions of Firefox Portable here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/portableapps/files/Mozilla%20Firefox%2C%20Portable%20Ed./

Answer (score 4):

Selenium IDE & firebug can work on any versions (mostly above v-31.0) of Mozilla FF. both are Firefox plugins so they don't affect on any versions. If you are asking about Selenium WebDriver & ff versions then it may differs from version to version & Selenium java jars. but my perspective IDE & firebug can work on any versions of ff.